# Aggregation Using Mongo Repository- Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In Mongo Repository when we define custom query so we use @Query annotion. like below
`@Query(value =  "{$group:{emp_country:$emp_country,emp_city:$emp_city}},$project:{emp_country:1,emp_city:1,_id=0}")`.
in query I want to use aggregation method like $group,$project so how to achieve this without using aggregation with mongo template, use only mongo repository.
sample Data:

```
[
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

expected Output

```
[
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@Aggregation` annotation is available since spring-data-mongodb `2.2`

```java
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{ $group: ... }", "{ $project : ... }")
List<Aggregate> aggregationViaAnnotatedRepositoryMethod();
```

More details can be found in the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation).

Comment: okay, it might be work but how can we pass pipeline value as an argument in method dynamically change from the service layer. in-service layer I have Aggregation Object.

Comment: Please, have a look at the Reference Documentation! You'll find everything (including how to use placeholders) there.